# What does this MobX syntax do? Where is it documented?

Tags: javascript, mobx

The latest MobX 6.0.1 release has a syntax that appears in the example app at https://codesandbox.io/s/minimal-observer-p9ti4 that I don't understand.

The code is:

```
const TimerView = observer(({ timer }: { timer: Timer }) => (
  <span>Seconds passed: {timer.secondsPassed}</span>
));
```

The syntax `function({arg1,arg2})` I've seen and understand, but not
`function({arg1: {arg1: arg2}})` and since the MobX docs don't help; I'm asking here.

### What I've tried

So I looked up the docs for MobX observer and found https://mobx.js.org/api.html#observer-1 which doesn't help.  It says:

```
observer

Usage: observer(component)

A higher order component you can use to make a functional or class based React component re-render when observables change.
```

I'm looking over the website more but hopefully this question and forthcoming answer will help someone else out.

Comment: The code in your link is TypeScript, not JavaScript -- it has extension `.tsx`

Comment: i using mobx in current native project and i know documentation sucks..... but they help me :  [Maksim Ivanov](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKNls_FReXI) [Ben Awad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQiMXRsO4o4&t=218s)

Comment: Oh, well that explains it!  Then the 2nd `{timer: Timer}` is the structure of the variable.  Thanks.  I missed that.

Comment: As mentioned. It is Typescript. Are you familiar with C or Java? In C/Java types are defined as `number x` but Typescript uses `x: number`. Therefore the observer has a type `x: Object` and not any kind of object but an object that looks like `{timer: somevalue}` where again the type of `timer` is the `Timer` class as defined by `timer: Timer`. The rest is regular argument destructuring. In javascript the syntax is simply `observer(({timer}) => { ...`

Comment: ... everything after the `:` is Typescript stuff and not part of javascript syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying that your `observer` callback has an object argument with a `timer` property. That `timer` property is of type `Timer`.

The object is then destructured to extract the `timer` property to the variable `timer`.

Think of it like this

```js
interface Timer {
  secondsPassed: number
}
interface Component {
  timer: Timer
}
const TimerView = observer((obj: Component) => (
  <span>Seconds passed: {obj.timer.secondsPassed}</span>
));
```